# Bash script - match and merge files

Tags: string, bash, loops, cat

I want to merge files based on the first few strings. For example:

```
ab_2012.01.01_v01.txt
ab_2012.01.01_v02.txt

ab_2014.09.28_v01.txt
ab_2014.09.28_v02.txt
```

I can manually use `cat` to merge the two versions. However, how do I create a loop to match the characters up to the `"v01"` suffix and merge them? They all live in the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
for file in *_v01.txt ; do
    cat "$file" "${file%_v01.txt}_v02.txt" > "${file%_v01.txt}_merged.txt"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for formatting my question and the answer works great! There are still some tweaks I'll have to do before I can use it 100%, and the website you provided (still loading) seems like a great resource to start looking!